# PHPExcel - load only filtered data

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have file like [this](https://mega.co.nz/#!FgIima5A!kuOxYQa1xg0Z0qk87tuQocbswuiv6UjD8Qfs5W7OlPk)

I want to load only two visible row in this example.
I do not know how I can do it.

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$excel = $reader->load($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name']);
$data = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true);
```

When loading the file in PHPExcel shows all 8769 rows.

I have to do it in such a way as filtered data will always be different.

Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to select two random rows from the worksheet?

Comment: No, I try to select only the filtered (visible) rows from the worksheet.

Comment: Then loop over the worksheet, one row at a time, and check the visibility of that row.

Comment: I think that filtering does not change the visibility of the column. I just need data that is filtered in the worksheet

Comment: Filtering changes the visibility of a row, not of a column

Comment: How to check the visibility of row?

Comment: By calling the getVisible() method of the Row Dimension, as my answer shows

Answer (score 1):

If you only want visible rows, then you need to write a bit of code that will loop over the rows selecting only those that are visible

Something like:

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$excel = $reader->load($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name']);
$highestColumn = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
$data = [];
foreach ($excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    if ($excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row->getIndex())->getVisible()) {
        $data[] = $excel->getActiveSheet()
            ->rangeToArray('A' .$row->getIndex().':'.$highestColumn.$row->getIndex());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot!

Working great as soon swapped "getIndex ()" to "getRowIndex ()"

```
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$excel = $reader->load($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name']);
$data = [];
foreach ($excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() as $row) {
if ($excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($row->getRowIndex())->getVisible()) {
   $data[] = $excel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A' .$row->getRowIndex().':'.'BB'.$row->getRowIndex());
   }
}
```